# How to deploy custom modules in apache-fineract?

Tags: apache-fineract

I'm trying to use the custom note module included in fineract but can not make it work. Does anybody made it work? The documentation says:

*Custom modules (better: the JAR files) only need to be dropped in Fineract’s libs folder if you run Fineract from the Spring Boot JAR file ...*

But not sure where this lib folder is.

Thanks very much
regards;
fernando